# Magento 1.9.3.1 Sales Order Grid limit records

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, order-grid

I have a Magento store running with over 18,000 order records all the other pages within admin load within 1 - 2 seconds apart from Sales>Orders this can take anything between 5 - 20 seconds to load.

It is set at the standard displaying 20 records per page | Total 18000 records found

How can I either speed this page load time or limit the records to the last 3,000 total records so the page loads faster?

I have optimised the Database, Optimised the Server everything I've done has improved the rest of the site on the frontend and backend apart from this page?

Any help appreciated as this is having an impact on the daily running of the site for anyone working within the admin.

Comment: If your grid is customized then you should check the for the column which is taking too much time to load.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: you need to debug it, disable extensions which is related to it and check it.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the grid prepareCollection method by this code

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
  $this->setDefaultLimit(200);
  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
  $collection->getSelect()->limit(300);
  $this->setCollection($collection);
  return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

You have to set the default limit to 200 and select query limit to 3000. This will give you 15 grid pages with total 3000 order.